# how to find out URLs of android apps

Tags: android, android-webview

URLs of LinkedIn

```
linkedin://you
linkedin://profile/[profile id]
linkedin://group/[group id]
```

using these links i can open linked app via my web page , same way i need to know the other application URLs also , how to find out them?

Comment: it depends on how other applications handle action, may be LinkedIn app handle you mentioned above actions

Comment: how can i find intents for other applications ?

Comment: try decompile those apk and check AndroidManifest

Comment: to decompile use aapt d <path_to_apk>